# ¿Como podria resolver este problema al momento de ordenar los valores?

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando una tarea que consiste en realizar un programa el cual pida una temperatura promedio de los dias de la semana, y que los ordene mediante un metodo de seleccion (en este caso me toco burbuja),pero al momento de mostrar los resultados un valor no es mostrado y sale un error numerico.Comparto mi codigo y espero su ayuda.Muchas gracias.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>





int main(){
    
   string dias[7]= {"Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo"};
   int i,j,aux;
   double temperaturas[7];
   
   
   for ( i=0;i<7;i++){
       cout<<"Ingrese temperatura promedio del dia "<<dias[i]<<":"; 
                   cin>>temperaturas[i];
       
       }
       for (i=0;i<7;i++){
       for(j=0;j<7;j++){
           if(temperaturas[j]>temperaturas[j+1]){
               aux= temperaturas[j];
               temperaturas[j]=temperaturas[j+1];
               temperaturas[j+1]=aux;
           }
       }
   }
           
           
   cout<<"Temperaturas de forma ascendente: \n";
   for(i=0;i<8;i++){
       cout<<temperaturas[i]<<"\n";
   }
   
   cout<<"Temperaturas de forma descendente: \n";
   for(i=7;i>=0;i--){
       cout<<temperaturas[i]<<"\n";
   }
   
   
   
   
   
   getch ();
   return 0 ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, esto

```
temperaturas[j+1]
```

Te esta leyendo un indice que o te va a regresar basura o te va a reventar el programa en el último elemento, porque acuerdate que los indices van de 0 a j - 1;

```
i=0;i<8;i++
```

Aqui estas poniendo 8 en lugar de 7

```
i=7;i>=0;i--
```

Aqui empiezas desde 7 en lugar de desde n-1 (6), que sería el máximo indice

Answer (score 0):

Si declaras un array de esta forma:

```
double temperaturas[7];
```

Estás creando una estructura en memoria con capacidad para 7 valores de tipo `double`, los cuales serán accesibles a través de los índices en el rango [0,6]. Cualquier valor que no sea uno de esos impliciará un acceso a memoria no perteneciente al array.

Con esta información en mente, vamos con los errores:

```
for (i=0;i<7;i++){
for(j=0;j<7;j++){
    if(temperaturas[j]>temperaturas[j+1]){
        aux= temperaturas[j];
        temperaturas[j]=temperaturas[j+1];
        temperaturas[j+1]=aux;
    }
}
```

El primer problema de este bucle doble es que estás declarando dos índices `i` y `j`, pero solo usas `j`. El ignorar uno de los índices hace que se te complique la tarea de ordenar el array ... acabas usando `j` dos veces y ahí es cuando te da por poner `j+1`. Pues bien, teniendo en cuenta que estás iterando en el rango [0,6], cuando `j==6`,  `j+1==7` ... ya estás accediendo a posiciones de memoria que no son del array.

Otro error que estás cometiendo es que estás realizando demasiadas iteraciones. El algoritmo de la burbuja asegura la posición de un elemento en cada iteración del bucle principal, Es decir, cuando `i==4`, se entenderá que los elementos cuyos índices sean inferiores a 4 ya deberían estar ordenados.

Esto, hablando en cristiano, quiere decir que el rango de iteración del segundo bucle depende del estado del primer bucle. Esto se expresa así:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<7; j++){
```

El resto del bucle, una vez corregido, debería quedar así:

```
if (temperaturas[j] > temperaturas[i]){
    int aux = temperaturas[j];
    temperaturas[j] = temperaturas[i];
    temperaturas[i] = aux;
}
```

Como puedes ver, el bucle que muestra las temperaturas de forma ascendente usa un rango incorrecto:

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
```

Como hemos dicho, el rango debería ser [0,6], y tu estás iterando en el rango [0,7].

Corregido quedaría así:

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
```

Y pasamos al último bucle, otro que tiene problemas:

```
for(i=7;i>=0;i--){
```

Aquí vuelves a iterar en el rango [0,7], o [7,0], como prefieras verlo. El problema aquí está en el valor inicial de `i`, debería ser `6`  o `7-1`, como prefieras:

```
for(int i=7-1; i>=0; i--){
```

Nota que estoy añadiendo `int` en todos los bucles. En C++ es posible declarar variables en la definición del bucle. Reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible te ahorrará un montón de quebraderos de cabeza, es una práctica que podrías ir adquiriendo desde el principio.

Con los cambios que te he propuesto bastaría, en tu caso, con eliminar la línea:

```
int i,j,aux;
```

Y declarar `i` en aquellos bucles por los que no hemos pasado en esta respuesta.

También te sugiero no hacer uso de `getch()`. Esta llamada forma parte de la herencia de C. C++ usa *streams* propios para interactuar con la entrada/salida diferentes de los usados en C (y en las funciones heredadas de este lenguaje). Así, `getch()` actúa sobre `stdin` mientras que en C++ tenemos `std::cin`. No es buena idea mezclar ambos usos. Si estás en C++, usa `std::cin`:

```
std::cin.get();
```

Otra herramienta que deberías acostumbrarte a usar son las constantes. Evita el uso de los números mágicos en beneficio de las constantes. Tu código será más legible y seguro.

C++, como la mayoría de lenguajes, no es algo estático. Periódicamente se van publicando nuevos estándares que hacen que el programa evolucione.

Así, el estándar C++11 (publicado en el año 2011), añadió una nueva palabra al lenguaje `constexpr`. Este símbolo fuerza al compilador a calcular el resultado de la expresión en tiempo de compilación. Para versiones anteriores del lenguaje puedes usar `static const`:

```
// C++11 y posteriores
constexpr int MaxTemperaturas = 7;

// Versiones anteriores
static const int MaxTemperaturas = 7;
```

Con esta constante tu programa ahora quedaría así:

```
int main(){
    
    string dias[MaxTemperaturas]= {"Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo"};
    double temperaturas[MaxTemperaturas];
   
   
    for (int i=0; i<MaxTemperaturas; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese temperatura promedio del dia "<<dias[i]<<":"; 
        cin>>temperaturas[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<MaxTemperaturas; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<MaxTemperaturas; j++)
        {
            if (temperaturas[j] > temperaturas[i])
            {
               int aux = temperaturas[j];
               temperaturas[j]=temperaturas[i];
               temperaturas[i]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
           
    cout<<"Temperaturas de forma ascendente: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<MaxTemperaturas; i++)
    {
        cout<<temperaturas[i]<<"\n";
    }
   
    cout<<"Temperaturas de forma descendente: \n";
    for(int i=MaxTemperaturas-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout<<temperaturas[i]<<"\n";
    }
   
    std::cin.get();
    return 0 ; 
}
```